# Increment internal redmine counters

Tags: database, redmine

I migrated our current redmine database content to a new redmine instance on another server, with its own database.

The problem is that when I create something new on my new redmine instance (e.g: a new issue), redmine has internal counters to insert new elements in its database, which end up in primary key collisions because of IDs already existing from my old redmine database.

I solved this by trying to create new elements a number of times high enough to increment the internal counters and avoid primary key collisions.

Does anyone know a proper way to solve this issue? Especially when I have to deal with millions of existing IDs in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redmine doesn't handle these primary key ids. They are generated by your database instead.

For each table, there is a special counter to generate these IDs on insert. For MySQL, you [can set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-auto-increment.html) the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value of a table. For Postgres, you have to adapt the sequence for the table's primary key using [`setval`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-sequence.html).

Generally, when moving databases from one database server to another, you should make sure to preserve the `AUTO_INCREMENT` or sequence values. The common dump tools have options for that.

Comment: Thank you, using `setval` on my tables did it!

Answer (score 0):

When Redmine database is moved between two servers, and if version differs it is necessary to perform database upgrade:

It is the following command:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

If you have installed any plugins, you should also run their database migrations:

```
bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but actually, I was unable to do that... I performed the database upgrade with a python script I wrote myself because I don't have access to the old redmine server, I could only perform sql queries on its database. Plus, this old redmine has mysql database, and the new one has postgresql... But now, on my new server, I have all access rights to do (almost) anything I want.

Comment: No no :) you copy database to new server then run those scripts on new server configured to access old database... Btw, I wrote about that extesnively https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/redmine-cookbook